# storing information from 200+ tweets in a dataframe

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get data from the twitter-API using tweepy and store it in a usable dataframe. I used some code from a tutorial and tried to adapt it but encountered a few problems.

```
 class TweetAnalyzer():

    def tweets_to_data_frame(self, tweets):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

        df['id'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
        df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet.full_text) for tweet in tweets])
        df['date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
        df['source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
        df['likes'] = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
        df['retweets'] = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])
        df['quote'] = np.array([tweet.is_quote_status for tweet in tweets])
        df['location'] = np.array([tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets])
        df['hashtags'] = np.array([tweet.entities.user_mentions.name for tweet in tweets])

        return df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    twitter_client = TwitterClient()
    tweet_analyzer = TweetAnalyzer()

    api = twitter_client.get_twitter_client_api()

    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump", count=200, tweet_mode='extended')

    df = tweet_analyzer.tweets_to_data_frame(tweets)

    print(df.head(10))
    df.to_csv('trump.csv', index=False)
```

My first problem is, that with this method I can't get more than 200 tweets. I read in another post to use a Cursor object. So I made the following change:

```
tweets = Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name="realDonaldTrump", tweet_mode='extended').items()
```

this however results in the following error, when the function tries to attach more than one row to the dataframe:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I would appreciate any help!

Additionally I have two other issues, but these are more nice to know.

1) I would like to have a seperate row for the hashtags. When I run the code I get an error because naturally not every tweet contains hashtags. Is it possible to run the code and fill the row with 'null' if there is no hashtag?

2) The date that I get in the date row is my own timezone which is CET. Is it possible to take the time from the timezone the tweet was posted?

Would be awesome if somebody has some advice!